# What is overflow_usub?

Tags: c, linux-kernel

Linus Torvalds has recently made it to mainstream news with a rant over a pull request. This pull request included a function, `overflow_usub`, which is apparently non-standard and uses some kind of compiler magic. As a result of the widespread reporting of this rant, it is near-impossible to find any useful information about this function. My question is: what is `overflow_usub`, when should it be used and what kind of compiler magic does it require?

Comment: Given what Linus said, I would not use it... Ever...

Comment: @Thomas Linus isn't god.

Comment: @MillieSmith did I write that somewhere? :)

Comment: @Thomas, No, my apologies for the abrasiveness. I just don't think his argument is compelling. Linus was right that the code was terribly written and ineligible, but Linus didn't give any arguments to never use `overflow_usub` (except saying that you shouldn't). I think `overflow_usub` has its place - it just needs to be used correctly like pretty much everything else (gotos, regex, coding in general).

Comment: Er... illegible*. Ineligible for checkin though ;).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The function `overflow_usub` is defined as:

```
static inline bool overflow_usub(unsigned int a, unsigned int b, unsigned int *res){
  *res = a - b;
  return *res > a ? true : false;
}
```

It will check for integer overflows in subtraction and doesn't involve any compiler magic. It's usually a fallback, if the compiler has no `__builtin_usub_overflow`.

Comment: Its an overflow detection for unsigned substraction. If a unsigned substraction overflows, the result will be bigger than the first operand, as the overflow occurs. Thats the check. Imagine `a = 10` and `b = 20` and that (for simplification) as 8bit, the result would be `res = 245` as it overflowed and is unsigned. Thus `res > a` is `true` and the overflow is detected. But it has flaws in it that would not get detected... e.g. `b=255`

Comment: He's asking what the point of `? true : false` is. There is none. I see that useless code way too much.

Comment: @Thomas There is no point in it: the code is simply not written well - that is also why Linus complaint about it.

Comment: @Constantin It's not so much about the implementation as the semantics of `overflow_usub`. Linus mostly notes that this function does too many things (subtracting *and* checking for overflow) and thus makes the code less readable (besides being yet another function to learn about).

Comment: Aaargh it is supposed to be C code and c does NOT have bool, C++ has bool!

Comment: @Nils In C99 there exists bool - it's defined in stdbool.h

Answer (score 1):

It's a (possibly optimised) overflow detecting unsigned subtraction: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0103r0.html#Overflow and *can* be done as compiler intrinsics, so *could* be implemented to be higher performance than the readable code Linus uses. *could* being the operative word here, as who knows? The optimisation is probably not that useful in many cases (certainly not in the Linux example) and yet the code is more unreadable. Hence the rant.